# EF with a Linked Server?

Tags: entity-framework-core

Is it possible to use Entity Framework with a linked server?

I was hoping to do database first, but the UI asks you to "Select or enter a database name."  I'm wondering if that may not be possible.

If it's not, I could settle for code first, though my googling has yet to show me any explicit evidence that it works there either.

Probably a dumb question but I don't want to spend too much time only to find out it can't be done yet.

Comment: You mean without a server? If you planned on doing the database first, then you should have name to select or enter....

Comment: I'm required to use an oracle database, and as far as I understand Oracle hasn't begun to support core yet.  As a workaround I thought I could go with a SQL Server linked server pointed at the oracle database.